# How to convert $V/A$ (Volts/Ampere) data to $T/s$ (Tesla/seconds)?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, unit-conversion

I have a list of time domain electromagnetic data that I need to invert, but the equipment provides the data in V/A and the software to invert need it in db/dt [T/s]. Would someone help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in terms of dimensional analysis, which is what I think you ask for, I can give you this: 
$$1 \frac{V}{A} = 1 \frac{kg \cdot m^2}{A^2 \cdot s^3}$$
and
$$1 \frac{T}{s} = 1 \frac{kg}{A \cdot s^3}$$
So we can see the conversion factor you need is $\frac{A}{m^2}$, since we can see that:

$$ 1 \frac{T}{s} = 1 \frac{A}{m^2} \cdot \frac{V}{A} $$

($A$ amperes, $V$ volts, $kg$ kilograms, $m$ meters, $s$ seconds and $T$ teslas)

Hope this is what you were looking for!

Comment: So, if I multiply my data for the equipment current( A ) and divide by the loop area (m2) would give me the field db/dt (T/s) ?

Comment: Yes, the $m^2$ term refers to the area of the loop, just as in Faraday’s Law.